# Quaternion Slerp and Lerp implementation (with overshoot)

Tags: unity, mathematics, quaternion

I am working with Unity (C#) and was looking for an implementation of Slerp and possibly Lerp that allow overshoot (progress not strictly limited to 0..1 range).  I want to do some tweening animation using an elastic ease-out function.  My ease-out function returns values slightly outside the 0..1 range in order to get an oscillating-around-the-target effect.  The problem is that Unity's Quaternion Lerp and Slerp functions appear to clamp the progress input in the 0..1 range.

Implementation code in any language would be helpful.  I don't know enough about Quaternion math to write this myself.

Comment: Have tried applying your elastic easing function to the euler angles?

Answer (score 2):

Here’s a little example. Suppose you slerp `q0` and `q1` with a value of `t = 0.2` and a value of `t = 0.4`. This gives you a quaternion `s(0.2)` and a quaternion `s(0.4)`. Quaternion multiplication also gives us the following:

```
s(0.2) = q0 * inverse(q0) * s(0.2)
              '——————— K ————————'
```

So we have a value `K` which, when right-multiplied with `q0`, gives us `s(0.2)`. Now intuitively we can guess that multiplying twice will give us `s(0.4)`:

```
s(0.4) = q0 * inverse(q0) * s(0.2) * inverse(q0) * s(0.2)
              '——————— K ————————'   '——————— K ————————'
```

Simplifying:

```
s(0.4) = s(0.2) * inverse(q0) * s(0.2)
```

We can use this technique to slerp with values greater than `1` by just dividing by two. Which brings us to the following pseudocode:

```
quat slerp_generic(quat q0, quat q1, float t)
{
    // If t is too large, divide it by two recursively
    if (t > 1.0)
    {
        quat tmp = slerp_generic(q0, q1, t / 2);
        return tmp * inverse(q0) * tmp;
    }

    // It’s easier to handle negative t this way
    if (t < 0.0)
        return slerp_generic(q1, q0, 1.0 - t);

    return slerp(q0, q1, t);
}
```

---

**Edit**: the above code works great for `slerp`; for `lerp` however you’re going to get discontinuities in the derivative which you may not want. This code uses a similar technique and will work better for `lerp`:

```
quat lerp_generic(quat q0, quat q1, float t)
{
    // If t is too large, subtract 1.0 from it recursively
    if (t > 1.0)
    {
        quat tmp = lerp_generic(q0, q1, t - 1.0);
        return tmp * inverse(q0) * q1;
    }

    // It’s easier to handle negative t this way
    if (t < 0.0)
        return lerp_generic(q1, q0, 1.0 - t);

    return lerp(q0, q1, t);
}
```

Comment: This is a nice little gem.